# Android: Why is subsequent code preventing .setText() for TextView from working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, settext

**Update:  I've discovered that code after my call to `updatePercentage` is preventing the `.setText` from working.  I've updated my code below to show the call to `calcAndDisplayResults` from button_Convert, and the code for `calcAndDisplayResults`.  When I remove the call to `calcAndDisplayResults` the `.setText` before this call works correctly.  Why would later code prevent earlier code from working?**

I'm attempting to update the text of a `TextView` object using `.setText()` to show an updated completion percentage value on the content_main layout (which is included in the activity_main layout).  I'm updating the text via a private method I've written named `updatePercentage` which is called from the `onClick` method of `MainActivity` when various buttons are pressed.  The `.setText` works (i.e. updates the text of the `TextView`) when updatePercentage is called from some locations within `onClick`, but not from others.  Specifically, it works when entering the `onClick` method, works when button_3 is clicked, but doesn't work (i.e. doesn't update the text of the `TextView`) when button_Convert is clicked.  Other methods in the button_Convert switch case (which are called after `updatePercentage`) work properly.

I searched the StackOverflow database and found other folks with `setText` questions, but none appear to address the issue I'm experiencing.  My development environment is Android Studio (2.1.2), with all known relevant updates.  I'm experiencing the issues using the AVD device Galaxy Nexus API 23.  I'm new to Android/Java and would appreciate your assistance.

Here are the relevant portions of my code.

MainActivity.java:

```
...
import android.widget.TextView;
...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
...
private TextView percentComplete;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final String METHOD = "Method: onCreate";
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    percentComplete = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_PercentCompleteValue);
    ...

}

...

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    final String METHOD = "Method: onClick";

    currentValue = valueToConvert.getText().toString();

    int progressUpdate = 0;
    updatePercentage(progressUpdate);  //This one works...text updated to 0%

    ArrayList<String> goodWords = new ArrayList<>();

    Results_Adapter resultsAdapter = new Results_Adapter(this, goodWords);
    listResults.setAdapter(resultsAdapter);

    switch (view.getId()) {

        ...

        case R.id.button_3:
            valueToConvert.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%s%s", currentValue, "3"));

            progressUpdate = 3;
            updatePercentage(progressUpdate);  //This one works...text updated to 3%

            break;

        ...

        case R.id.button_Convert:
            progressUpdate = 20;
            updatePercentage(progressUpdate);  //This one doesn't work...text stays 0% or 3%, depending if I've clicked button_3 first

            calcAndDisplayResults();  //If I remove the call to this method, the code for updatePercentage works ????

            break;
    }
}

private void calcAndDisplayResults (){
    final String METHOD = "Method: calcAndDisplayResults";
    ArrayList<String> goodWords = new ArrayList<>();

    currentValue = valueToConvert.getText().toString();
    goodWords = convertNumbersToWords(currentValue);
    if (goodWords.size() == 0) {
        goodWords.add("<No equivalent words!>");
    }
    Results_Adapter resultsAdapter = new Results_Adapter(this, goodWords);
    listResults.setAdapter(resultsAdapter);
}

private void updatePercentage (int newPercentage){
    final String METHOD = "Method: updatePercentage";
    Log.v(LOG_CLASS, String.format(Locale.US, "%s; newPercentage: %d%%", METHOD, newPercentage));
    this.percentComplete.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d%%", newPercentage));
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/md_grey_200"
    tools:context="com.psmithe.combowords.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.psmithe.combowords.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_CodeToCovert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView_CodeToCovert"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorNumberKeys"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:maxWidth="120dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:minWidth="90dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorNumberKeys"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:maxWidth="120dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:minWidth="90dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="2\n(A B C)"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorNumberKeys"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:maxWidth="120dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:minWidth="90dp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="3\n(D E F)"
            android:textSize="12sp"/>

        ...

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_Convert"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="100"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorConvertKey"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Convert To Words"
            android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"/>

    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_percentComplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_percentCompleteLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Percent Complete:"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_PercentCompleteValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text=""/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_EquivalentWords"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_percentComplete"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorListViewBackground"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've also noticed when I click button_Convert, the first call to `updatePercentage` at the beginning of `onClick` (i.e. the call before the switch section) doesn't update the text value to 0%.  If I click any other button, that same call works.  Also, the logcat output from `updatePercentage` shows the correct value, even when called from the button_Convert switch case.

Comment: If you try posting the `calcAndDisplayResults ` method with a delay, do you see the correct percentage value flash?

Comment: @JMLord, wahoo!!  Your comment led me to run `calcAndDisplayResults` on a different thread, which caused `updatePercentage` to work correctly (once I adjusted `updatePercentage` to post the .setText to the UI Thread).  Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Fine, lets do that :) Glad my question helped you out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setText()` seems to be overriden.

If you try posting the `calcAndDisplayResults` method with a delay, do you see the correct percentage value flash?

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `@override` before the `onClick(View view)` method and you don't need to implement the `View.OnClickListener`(after AppCompatActivity) . The reason is that you've already defined the onClickListener in your xml file for the buttons, i.e.,for `button_Convert`, there is a line `android:onClick="onClick"` indicating that if you click this button, it will call the method `onClick`.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations and information, @Arron.  Unfortunately these changes didn't fix my issue.